# RxSwift access to indexPath.section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift, indexpath

guys Im totally new in Rxswift, is there is a way to do this scenario in RxSwift ?

What I got is this.. but problem is i dont have indexPath

```
datasource.sectionModels
        .asObservable()
        .bindTo(tableView.rx.items) { tableView, row, element in
            guard let sectionType = SectionType(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return 0 }

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: 0)

            var itemForIndexPath: SectionViewModel {
                return self.datasource.sectionModels.value[indexPath.section]
            }

            switch sectionType {
            case .nickTitle, .nickIfno:
                let infoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                    withIdentifier: InfoTableViewCell.name,
                    for: indexPath
                    ) as! InfoTableViewCell

                var datasource: InfoCellDatasourceProtocol = InfoCellNormalState(text: itemForIndexPath.text)
                if itemForIndexPath.errorStyle {
                    datasource = InfoCellErrorState(text: itemForIndexPath.text)
                }

                infoCell.configureCell(datasource: datasource)
            }
```

This is what I need in RxSwift

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let sectionType = SectionType(rawValue: indexPath.section) else { return UITableViewCell() }

    var itemForIndexPath: SectionViewModel {
        return self.datasource.sectionModels.value[indexPath.section]
    }

    switch sectionType {
    case .nickTitle, .nickInfo:
        let infoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: InfoTableViewCell.name,
            for: indexPath
            ) as! InfoTableViewCell

        var datasource: InfoCellDatasourceProtocol = InfoCellNormalState(text: itemForIndexPath.text)
        if itemForIndexPath.errorStyle {
            datasource = InfoCellErrorState(text: itemForIndexPath.text)
        }

        infoCell.configureCell(datasource: datasource)

        return infoCell
```

datasource snippet:

```
open class RegistrationNickDataSource: NickDatasourceProtocol {
    public var error: Variable<ErrorType>?
    public var success: Variable<Bool> = Variable(false)
    fileprivate let request = ValidateNameRequest()


    public var nickHints: Variable<[String]>?
    public var sectionModels: Variable<[SectionViewModel]> =  Variable([
    SectionViewModel(
        text: "your_nick_hint".localized,
        type: .info,
        errorStyle: false
    ),
    SectionViewModel(
        text: "your_nick_placeholder".localized,
        type: .input,
        errorStyle: false
    ),
    SectionViewModel(
        text: "your_nick_info".localized,
        type: .info,
        errorStyle: false
    )]
)
```

Thanks for every help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using [RxDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources). It will give you access to a cell's index path when you call `configureCell`.

Your data source and cell will be configured using something like:

```
func setupDataSource() 
{
    let dataSource = RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource<MySection>()

    dataSource.configureCell = { (theDataSource: TableViewSectionedDataSource<MySection>,                     
                                  theTableView,         
                                  theIndexPath,                                  
                                  item: MyItem) in
        let cell = theTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InfoTableViewCell.name,
                                                    for: theIndexPath) as! InfoTableViewCell

        /* Do any setup of the cell here. */

        return cell;
    }       

    dataSource.titleForHeaderInSection = { theDataSource, index in
        return theDataSource.sectionModels[index].header;
    }
}
```

You can leave out the types in the closure parameters if you have problems getting the types to be accepted. Swift can infer them for you.

---

Setting up structs for your custom data source including your section models would look something like the following:

```
/// Holds data to display.
struct MyItem
{
    var text: String
    var type: MyCustomEnum
    var errorStyle: Bool
}

/// Defines a section type for use with sections for the table.
struct MySection
{
    var header: String
    var items: [Item]
}

/// Tie your custom data model to SectionModelType.
extension MySection: SectionModelType
{
    typealias Item = MyItem

    init(original: MySection,
         items: [Item])
    {
        self = original
        self.items = items
    }
}
```

---

The penultimate step is to bind the data source by placing your sections into an Observable. The following code is an example where the function `sections()` returns an Observable of type `Observable<[MySection]>`:

```
sections()
    .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

---

Finally, getting the data to appear can be done using:

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
 {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     setupDataSource()
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example from the repo to make a sectioned table view:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/SimpleTableViewExampleSectioned/SimpleTableViewExampleSectionedViewController.swift

The upshot of it is that you have to instantiate a `RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource`.

However, I don't see in your code where you actually have sections. Sections in a UITableView imply a 2 dimensional array and you only have a 1 dimensional array...